# ASP.NET Core , Telerik grid, no data is displayed but controller action returns data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telerik-grid

In an ASP.NET MVC Core 3 project I have Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core.

I have hooked up a grid to a view, and the controller action is returning data, however the grid does not render the data.

I have subscribed to the error event on the grid, and that does not fire. I have also researched and it seems the way .NET Core handles serialization is the issue, between camel case and pascal case, so my Startup.cs has this:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews() 
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
```

But the grid does not render any of the records returned.

Grid definition:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Web.Models.DemoQueueViewModel>().Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => 
        { 
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
        })
        .Read("GridRead", "DemoQueue")
    )
)
```

Comment: Place `GridRead` method also,
because nested or child objects don't serialize to JSON format sometimes, and it causes that Telerik receive wrong response.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is related to the JSON serialization method, when using the `System.Text.Json` method to serialize the response data, it might not serialize the complex object.

Try to use Newtonsoft.Json to serialize response data, install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/) via Nuget, and then using the following code:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```